# method babel decorators isn't executed

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-decorator

I'm using the [babel 7 decorator plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators.html) and I have a simple class and I want to decorate each method in a simple try catch wrapper.

This is what've done:

```
const errorHandler = () => {
  return (target, property, descriptor) => {
    try {
      return descriptor
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('error from the decorator', e)
    }
  }
}
```

In this is a sample of my class:

```
class Example {
  @errorHandler
  addComponent() {
    throw new Error('Error')
  }
}
```

But when I'm executing the function it's not going throw the decorator before execution, only pre-evaluating when the class is being initialized.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `descriptor`, which is a function object and it gets executed by caller outside your `try/catch` block. To intercept exception - you should execute `descriptor` yourself.

The correct code is:

```js
const errorHandler = (target, property, descriptor) => {
  const original = descriptor.value;
  if (typeof original === 'function') {
    descriptor.value = async function(...args) {
      try {
        return await original.apply(this, args);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('error from the decorator', e)
      }
    }
  }
}

class Example {
  @errorHandler
  addComponent() {
    throw new Error('Error')
  }
}

new Example().addComponent();
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be the same if I'm using async functions?

Comment: Updated code to work with async and non-async functions

Comment: Cool, everything looks great until I'm using this in my functions, but why when I'm accessing this in my class methods I'm getting an exception about this, should I handle my methods differently because of the decorator?

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I think I might had problem with class functions. I have updated the code. It is now `async function(...args) {` instead of `async (...args) => {`, so it should properly set `this` for class methods.

Comment: Ohh finally thanks man, I ended up verifying against the constructor name instead of "typeof" - this gave me the option to handle both async and regular functions differently;
and this problem with the arrow function, I've encountered it so many time, and it still amazes me that I don't think to check this.